# rails 3 validation on uniqueness on multiple attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I use Rails 3.0.0.beta4

I want to add a validation on uniqueness on two attributes, that means that my model is valid if the couple of `'recorded_at'` and `'zipcode'` is unique.

On one attribute here is the syntax

```
validates :zipcode, :uniqueness => true
```

thanks

Answer (score 345, accepted):

In Rails 2, I would have written:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :zipcode, :scope => :recorded_at
```

In Rails 3:

```
validates :zipcode, :uniqueness => {:scope => :recorded_at}
```

For multiple attributes:

```
validates :zipcode, :uniqueness => {:scope => [:recorded_at, :something_else]}
```

Comment: I would say that logically it makes more sense to say that you require `recorded_at` to be unique within the scope of a zipcode. 


`validate :recorded_at, : uniqueness => { :scope => :zipcode }`

Comment: you can still do it the rails 2 way, and I find that more readable unless you're doing several types of validation on the same property.

Comment: would you validate a group of three with `validates :zipcode, :uniqueness => {:scope => [:recorded_at, :something_else]}`?

Comment: I would add that if you want to use `:scope` on foreign keys, you need to use the `:fkey_id` symbols, instead of `:fkey` ones, even if a "basic" `:uniqueness` works on `:fkey`

Comment: You probably want to add a custom error msg like `, :message => ' is taken for this recorded date'`

Comment: How to add `allow_nil: true` to multiple scope arguments? For example, in above case, how to make `:recorded_at and :something_else` `allow_nil: true`

Comment: Rails 6.1 `validates :year_date, uniqueness: {scope: [:person_id, :location_id], message: '. Already an item for this person at this address on this date'}`

Answer (score 99):

### Multiple Scope Parameters:

```
class TeacherSchedule < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_uniqueness_of :teacher_id, :scope => [:semester_id, :class_id]
end
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_uniqueness_of

This should answer Greg's question.

Comment: Greg seemed more interested in using the 'validates' shortcut, so a quicker answer to his question is "yes"

Comment: This is quite important to know, I was looking exactly to this if I should use the _id (or not) when checking for associations in scopes.

Comment: This answer works in Rails 4.1.6

validates_uniqueness_of :cart_id, scope: [:location_id, :plug_id]

Answer (score 6):

Dont work for me, need to put **scope** in **plural**

> validates_uniqueness_of :teacher_id, :scope**s** => [:semester_id,
>   :class_id]