# Rails: Association model unique multiple foreign key constraint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, foreign-keys

I can't achieve what I want here, but I have the feeling it is possible in Rails.

I have two models and an association one.

```
class Object < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :object_types_asso, :object_types_asso_attributes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :object_types_asso, :allow_destroy => true


  has_many :types, :through => :object_types_asso
  has_many :object_types_asso

end

class Types < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :object_types_asso, :object_types_asso_attributes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :object_types_asso, :allow_destroy => true

  has_many :object, :through => :object_types_asso
  has_many :object_types_asso

end

class ObjectTypesAsso < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :object_id, :type_id

  belongs_to :object
  belongs_to :types

end
```

I'd like to have an active record unicity constraint on `ObjectTypesAsso` so that I don't have two `ObjectTypesAsso` records with the same `:object_id` and `:type_id` and so that when one exists, it gets updated instead of creating a new one (or ignored if updating is not possible).

How could I achieve that?

The second part of the question is how could I manage the assos doing something like:

```
object.update_attributes({:object_types_asso_attributes => [{:types_id => xx}, {:types_id => yy}]})
```

and it creates asso with `types_id=xx` and `types_id=yy` if they don't exist, AND deletes `types_id=zz` if it existed since it is not in the list. The idea is to have a checkbox list that updates the associations wether it is checked or not.

Could I also do this?

Thanks

Comment: are you looking for has_many :through?

Comment: Your right, I forgot to add it in my example. But that's not what I am looking for.

Comment: I think the @dyanisse answer should be accepted answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first question, you want ObjectTypesAsso to be unique on :object_id and :type_id attributes

```
validates :object_id, :uniqueness => {:scope => :type_id}
```

[rails 3 validation on uniqueness on multiple attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276110/rails-3-validation-on-uniqueness-on-multiple-attributes)

For the second question, if I understood what you wan to do, you can ovewrite the list of types like this:

```
object.types = [Types.find(xx), Types.find(yy)]
```