# Validate uniqueness relatively to the parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I have a `post` model and a `keyword` model (with a `name` attribute), and a post has_many keywords.
I want to validate the uniqueness of keywords, but relatively to its post, not to all keywords.

What I mean is: `first_post` and `second_post` can both have the keyword `apple`, but they can't have it twice. I'd like to avoid the duplication.

If I just add in the `keyword` model:

```
validates :name, uniqueness: true
```

It will check uniqueness of `name` among all the keywords.
How can I precise that it should only be for its post ?

EDIT:
I did add:

```
validates :name, uniqueness: { scope: post_id }
```

to the keyword.rb file.
I now get an error:

```
undefined local variable or method `post_id' for #<Class:0x007f8fa46b7890>
```

But my keyword model has a post_id attribute. Any idea on what could be causing this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [rails 3 validation on uniqueness on multiple attributes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276110/rails-3-validation-on-uniqueness-on-multiple-attributes)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use scope.

> :scope - One or more columns by which to limit the scope of the
>   uniqueness constraint.

```
validates :name, uniqueness: { scope: :post_id }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I get this error when submitting my form:
undefined local variable or method `post_id' for #<Class:0x007f8fa46b7890>

But my keyword model has a post_id attribute. Any idea on what could be causing this ?

Comment: Sorry my bad. There was a typo in my answer. `post_id` should be a symbol. Fixed it